# How to store callback in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, callback

```
function getChild2 (user, userid, level, callback) {
User.find({ 'parentId': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userid), 'active': true },
    { "_id": true, "firstName": true,"lastName": true,"userId": true,"rightLeg": true,"leftLeg": true, "userName": true, "children": true, "activePackage": true, "type": true, "styleClass": true, "expanded": true }).
            sort({ 'created': -1 }).exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
      console1.error('Error:User:Read: ' + errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err));
    } else {
      console1.log('Log:User:Read: user network response ' + JSON.stringify(users));
      user.children.push(users);
      users.forEach(function (val, i) {
        console.log('getchild2 ' + val._id);
        getChild2(val, val._id, level+1, null);
      });
      if (users.length === 0)
     {
       callback(user);
}
    }
});
```

I need to use the callback when users.length === 0 but on my iteration I am making the callback as null i.e at the end of loop callback is becoming  null,then it says the error callback is not a function.Then I thought of storing the callback function initially in a variable.

```
if (callback !== null) {
      toCall = callback;
}
 then...
if (users.length === 0 ) {
    toCall(users);
}
```

Now it says toCall is not a function.Can anyone please help me to solve this.Thanks.

Comment: Your recursive call to getChild2 passes `null` into the parameter `callback`.

Comment: @James this is what I want to fix.

Comment: Just pass callback instead of null.  Note that callback won't run when the whole process is done, rather it will run each time it hits a person with no parents.